# Операции с деньгами в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как правильно считать деньги в Python? Все-таки типа money нет, а всякие там float'ы вне закона для таких дел

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834657/python-what-is-the-accepted-money-calculation-technique

Comment: Есть модуль [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Comment: Деньги надо считать в копейках, а не рублях. Тогда и всякие там floatы не понадобятся.

Comment: @Эникейщик, есть такая штука как банковское (оно же бухгалтерское) округление, которое реализовано для decimal, но если хранить в копейках (int или float), то это нужно дополнительно реализовывать. Зачем изобретать велосипед, если уже есть готовое решение.

Comment: @insolor, в Python 3.x [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) - использует банковское округление вместо математического)

Comment: @Эникейщик, считать в копейках - хороший вариант, пока у вас из операций только сложение, вычитание и умножение на целые числа. Но если вы начнёте считать всякие НДС, скидки, и агентские отчисления, то вам таки придётся делить и умножать на всякие стрёмные коэффициенты, и у вас всё равно вылезут флоаты. Так что правильнее здесь использовать децимал.

Comment: Спасибо, парни! Буду юзать decimal